# Interceptors in Spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm triying to use interceptors in Spring, I need to implement an interceptor on all my Controllers to handle specific logic when their are called.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="warningInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>*.do</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="warningInterceptor" class="security.WarningInterceptor">
    <property name="activeApp" value="${myWarning}"/>
</bean>
```

Java class: WarningInterceptor

```
public class WarningInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

private int activeApp;
public int getActiveApp() { return activeApp; }
public void setActiveApp(int activeApp) {this.activeApp = activeApp;}

public boolean preHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (getActiveApp() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("/myWarning.do");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I start MyApp I'm always getting this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '' is defined

Comment: i cannot see anything wrong with this. have you try cleaning and rebuilding your whole project?

Comment: Yes, I thinks is related with the value "*.do" in mappings, but I don't know what happen :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappings property of SimpleUrlHandlerMapping should map URLs to handlers, and you only have a URL pattern listed.  It should be something like this:

```
 <property name="mappings">
    <props>
       <prop key="*.do">myAppController</prop>
     </props>
   </property>
```

EDIT:  Here's a better example.  This one uses the value tag instead of prop (either way works).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
    <value>
       *.do=myAppController
    </value>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myAppController" 
    class="com.example.MyAppController" />
```

Comment: Also look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html "Mappings to bean names can be set via the "mappings" property, in a form accepted by the java.util.Properties class, like as follows:
/welcome.html=ticketController /show.html=ticketController "

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with adding a getter/setter methods for activeApp variable in your interceptor. (WarningInterceptor)

Comment: If you look at the WarningInterceptor class, there are get and set for the activeApp propertie